# Can a relation be a partial order and an equivalence at the same time?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Can a relation be a partial order AND an equivalence at the same time?
For instance, if we have a set $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and a relation $R$ on $A$ defined as $R = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)\}$: this relation is reflexive, anti-symmetric, symmetric, and would it be considered transitive as well? If it is considered transitive, I suppose that it is an equivalence and a partial order at the same time.

Comment: Yes it can be. Your example is correct.

Comment: Simpler is $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two remarks:

(1) Equality is an equivalence relation which is also a partial order ($\leq$).

(2) An equivalence relation is never a strict partial order ($<$).

Comment: I don't think the equivalence relation on a set of size $1$ is a strict partial order either...

Comment: Thanks, You are right. I edited.

Comment: What do you mean, that every equivalence relation is a partial order? For instance, on a set B = {0, 1, 2}, the relation R = {(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (0, 2)} is an equivalence relation, because it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, but it is not a partial order, because it is not anti-symmetric, I think.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of quasi-orders. I have edited.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I was getting confused.

Comment: Isn't the empty relation on the empty set both an equivalence relation and a strict partial order?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it must be exactly like the one you propoes, that is all the equivalence classes must be of size one.

For if we had an equivalence class with at least two elements a,b we would $(a,b),(b,a)\in R$

so it would not satisfy antisymmetry

Comment: right, ty ${}{}{}$